# When " flutter upgrade", I get "Permission denied" error

Tags: flutter, github, dart, permissions, file-permissions

I would like to build a web application with Flutter. I followed this instruction. https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web
I use Windows 10, Windows Subsystems for Linux, Debian 10.

I installed Flutter SDK in `~/development/` directory and have already set the path.

I input this.

```
flutter channel beta
```

And get this result.

```
Switching to flutter channel 'beta'...
git: From https://github.com/flutter/flutter
git:    5f21edf8b..b041144f8  stable         -> origin/stable
git:  * [new branch]          CareF-macrobenchmark-typo-fix -> origin/CareF-macrobenchmark-typo-fix
git:    c0d537ad3..311ad4bde  dart_development_service -> origin/dart_development_service
git:    456d80b9d..2f7a59a8d  dev            -> origin/dev
git:    5f21edf8b..b041144f8  flutter-1.17-candidate.3 -> origin/flutter-1.17-candidate.3
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.19-candidate.2 -> origin/flutter-1.19-candidate.2
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.19-candidate.3 -> origin/flutter-1.19-candidate.3
git:  * [new branch]          flutter-1.19-candidate.4 -> origin/flutter-1.19-candidate.4
git:    eacd1c8de..746749244  master         -> origin/master
git:  * [new tag]             1.17.3         -> 1.17.3
git:  * [new tag]             1.19.0-2.0.pre -> 1.19.0-2.0.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.19.0-3.0.pre -> 1.19.0-3.0.pre
git:  * [new tag]             1.19.0-4.0.pre -> 1.19.0-4.0.pre
git: Switched to a new branch 'beta'
git: Branch 'beta' set up to track remote branch 'beta' from 'origin'.
Successfully switched to flutter channel 'beta'.
To ensure that you're on the latest build from this channel, run 'flutter
upgrade'
```

Next, I input this.

```
flutter upgrade
```

Then, I get this.

```
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine ef9215ceb2884ddf520d321bcd822d1461330876...
mv: cannot move '/home/kazu/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk' to
'/home/kazu/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk.old': Permission denied
```

So, I read this NOTE. https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web#set-up

```
The flutter upgrade command silently fails when origin points to a personal fork. 
To validate that origin points to https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git, 
run the following commands in the root directory of your local copy of the 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter repository:
```

Then, I input this.

```
cd ~/development/flutter/
git remote get-url origin
```

Then my terminal returned this.

```
https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

So, I tried again.

```
flutter upgrade
```

I got the same result.

```
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine ef9215ceb2884ddf520d321bcd822d1461330876...
mv: cannot move '/home/kazu/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk' to
'/home/kazu/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk.old': Permission denied
```

Next, I tried `sudo`

```
sudo flutter upgrade
```

Then I got this.

```
sudo: flutter: command not found
```

Could you give me any advice please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, The problem you got is the current user not have permission in `dart-sdk` folder. You need to re-check the permission or `dart-sdk` folder.

Example
run `ls -la` to see the details

`drwxr-xr-x  10 user-xxx  staff       320  6 Jun 10:18 dart-sdk`

If not current user, using `sudo chown` to change owner of `dart-sdk` folder.

try `flutter upgrade` again.

Update
Solution: (ref: github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17898)

- Manually rename dart-sdk to something else  resolved the problem.
- or run this command `git clean -xffd git pull flutter doctor` before flutter upgrade

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I checked ```ls -la``` and this is the result. ``` drwxr-xr-x 1 kazu kazu     4096 May 29 06:32 dart-sdk``` Current user is ```kazu```, so I have another problem.

Comment: Hi @KazuakiSuzuki, I found the problem you got in here: Solution: manually rename dart-sdk to something else <dart-sdk.old2> resolved the problem.

or run this command

git clean -xffd git pull flutter doctor before flutter upgrade [link]https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17898. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. Your solution worked perfectly. I tried ```git clean -xffd git pull flutter doctor before flutter upgrade```

Comment: Didn't work with me

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to call some `flutter` command and have such output:

```
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine 40441def692f444660a11e20fac37af9050245ab...
mv: rename /Library/Flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk
to /Library/Flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk.old: Permission denied
```

it means you do not have sufficient permissions or the file belongs to another user.

## What to do?

**1) Go to provided directory with this to the file.**

```
cd /Library/Flutter/bin/cache/
```

**2) Check who is the owner**
By listing all of the files:

```
ls -l
```

with output:
[image]

**3) Change owner of this file to you**

```
sudo chown -R $USER dart-sdk
```

provide password (needed by `sudo`) and click <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**4) Check again who is the owner**

file owner should be set for your current user

**5) Repeat your `flutter` command**