# Error: Error when reading '../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/collection-1.17.2/lib/collection.dart': Permission denied

Tags: flutter, macos

just make new project

I'm trying to do a new project, same problem
The system has been updated to 14 mac
and system has been updated flutter
try chmod a+rx android/gradlew
chmod a+rx android/gradlew
sudo xattr -c -r ../../Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart:
sudo softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
//==========
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           38.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): ../../Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart:10:8: Error: Error when reading '../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/collection-1.17.2/lib/collection.dart': Permission denied

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You might have permission problems. [Check your permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62273677/12695243), and also try clearing your cache. This could be the issue, especially if it broke after an update.

```
flutter pub cache repair
flutter clean && flutter pub get
```

If it not helped try to [clear Derived data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64351688/12695243)

Is it working on android, mac, web?