# Error when reading '../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/meta-1.10.0/lib/meta.dart': Permission denied

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

Device: Apple M1 Max
macOs Sonoma v14.1.2

Fresh install of flutter, flutter SDK is currently in the following location:

users/scott/documents/SDKs/flutter

When I create a new `flutter create my_cool_app` it creates no issues, when I run 'flutter run' I get

> Error (Xcode): Sandbox: rsync.samba(8678) deny(1) file-read-data
> /Users/scott/Documents/development/flutter-development/my_cool_app/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework
>
> Error (Xcode): Sandbox: rsync.samba(8678) deny(1) file-write-times
> /Users/scott/Documents/development/flutter-development/my_cool_app/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework
>
> Error (Xcode): Sandbox: rsync.samba(8680) deny(1) file-read-data
> /Users/scott/Documents/development/flutter-development/my_cool_app/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework/Flutter
>
> Error (Xcode): Sandbox: rsync.samba(8680) deny(1) file-write-create
> /Users/scott/Documents/development/flutter-development/my_cool_app/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework/.Flutter.pQRfY7
>
> Error (Xcode): Sandbox: rsync.samba(8680) deny(1) file-read-data
> /Users/scott/Documents/development/flutter-development/my_cool_app/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
>
> Error (Xcode): Sandbox: rsync.samba(8680) deny(1) file-write-create
> /Users/scott/Documents/development/flutter-development/my_cool_app/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework/_CodeSignature/.CodeResources.ZP7r4T
>
> Error (Xcode): Sandbox: dart(8646) deny(1) file-read-data
> /Users/scott/Documents/development/flutter-development/my_cool_app/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/.last_build_id
>
> Error (Xcode):
> ../../../SDKs/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/foundation.dart:12:1:
> Error: Error when reading
> '../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/meta-1.10.0/lib/meta.dart':
> Permission denied
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching
> application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

I've tried what is shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62273109/when-flutter-upgrade-i-get-permission-denied-error/62273677#62273677), but the problem still remains, I've checked what flutter channel I'm on:

```
Flutter channels:
  master (latest development branch, for contributors)
  main (latest development branch, follows master channel)
  beta (updated monthly, recommended for experienced users)
* stable (updated quarterly, for new users and for production app releases)
```

Update

Resolved:

Error (Xcode): Sandbox: rsync.samba(8678) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/scott/Documents/development/flutter-development/my_cool_app/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flutter.framework

But I now get the one error, which is

Error (Xcode): ../../../SDKs/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/foundation.dart:12:1: Error: Error when reading '../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/meta-1.10.0/lib/meta.dart':
Permission denied

Comment: try this * flutter pub cache clean
* flutter clean
* flutter pub cache repair
* flutter pub get

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this error, I've resolved it by doing a fresh install of flutter again, deleted the Flutter folder that's originally downloaded, then removed the following files / folders, note these are hidden

.dart
.dart-tools
.dartServer
.flutter
.flutter-devtools
.pub-cache

restarted machine

Installed flutter, following the steps outlined on Flutter website.